# Ifstream trouble

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have the following code. It compiles fine, but it shows me that string is "E#*^$*$@$$$$$$$".
Any ideas why?

```
ifstream InFile(Filename);
if (!InFile)
    return false;
std::string Name;
Song *pSong;

for (int a = 0; a < Playlist.size(); a++)
{
    delete Playlist[a];
}
Playlist.clear();

while (true)
{
    if (!InFile)
        break;

    pSong = new Song();

    std::getline(InFile, Name, '\n');
    pSong->File = const_cast<char*>(Name.c_str());
    std::getline(InFile, Name, '\n');
    pSong->Volume = atof(Name.c_str());

    Playlist.push_back(pSong);
}
```

Playlist: `std::vector<Song*>Playlist;`

Comment: This is not safe: `pSong->File = const_cast<char*>(Name.c_str());` You are now having a non-const access to a std::string internals. Why not make `pSong.File` an `std::string` and make a copy? And which string is "that string" exactly, which is faulty?

Comment: What is `Song::File` and why is it not a `std::string`? Then it should just be `pSong->File = Name;` (besides the fact you probably don't need to allocate a `Song` with `new`...)

Comment: A copy of a pointer is no copy of content (lookup dangling pointer/reference)

Comment: @crashmstr Indeed, it's  better to use an `std::list<Song>` and fill them with `emplace_back`.

Comment: Song::File is char* because i'm using FMOD lib 
@DieterLücking I know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problematic line.

```
pSong->File = const_cast<char*>(Name.c_str());
```

You are storing a pointer to a memory that won't be valid after you read the next line of text from the file.

Change it to:

```
pSong->File = strdup(Name.c_str());
```

If your platform doesn't have `strdup`, here's a simple implementation.

```
char* strdup(char const* s)
{
   char* ret = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
   strcpy(ret, s);
   return ret;
}
```

**Caution**
Since you are allocating memory when you use `strdup`, you have to make sure that you deallocate it.

You have the option of using `new` to allocate memory since you are using C++. If you use `new` to allocate memory, you have to use `delete` to deallocate the memory. If you use `malloc` to allocate memory, like shown in this answer, you have to use `free` to deallocate the memory.

Comment: Sorry - strdup is evil

Comment: It's better not to use `char *` for strings in C++, it's a C construct. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Ok, this is C++: don't use `malloc`, and the better solution is to change the class to use a `std::string` and not C strings.

Comment: @tillaert im using c lib (FMOD) so that's why `char*`

Comment: If you have to use strdup, you should also `free` the pointer when you are done.

Comment: @tillaert good point. I updated the answer to include that point.

Comment: @DieterLücking Can you please elaborate on the "`strdup` is evil" statement?